# Open <a> in a new window. But standard is _blank

Tags: javascript, drupal, hyperlink, target

I have a Drupal website. I have a RSS feed with . Ahref links with target blank. But there is a bug in Drupal CMS. When i clicking on the links. Than the link open in the same window and a new window.

How can i fix this with javascript. Can i make a script that open links with target blank in a new window. And open not in the same window?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Perhaps posting a sample of the markup in question would help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm.

note that u must call event.preventDefault() method to avoid default behavior.

```
  window.onload = function(){        
        var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); 
        for (atag in aTags)
        {
            atag.onclick = function(event){             
                 var target = atag.getAttribute("target");           
                 if ( target == "_blank")
                 {
                    var href = atag.getAttribute("href");
                    window.open(href,'mywindow','width=400,height=200')
                    event.preventDefault();
                 }
           };
        }
    };
```

Comment: the code that i have wrote here is jquery.and you can change it to js .

Comment: But, how can i check on al the a elements with target blank.

Comment: you can check it with getAttribute() method.

Comment: i have edited the code.now using it is as easy as copying and pasting into script tag.